# Jquery functions not working in a modal of Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, external

I use Bootstrap v2.X in my proyect and I want to open a file external using modal function.

First, the code I should use is:

```
<a href="view_graphics.php" class="btn btn-warning btn-large" data-toggle="modal">Graphics</a>
```

but it doesn't work for me. Then I use:

```
<a href="view_graphics.php" id="graphics" class="btn btn-warning btn-large">Graphics</a>
```

and I put code Jquery:

```
$('a#graphics').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            if (url.indexOf('#') == 0) {
                $(url).modal('open');
            } else {
                $.get(url, function(data) {
                    $('<div class="modal hide fade modal-graphics">' + data + '</div>').modal();
                }).success(function() { $('input:text:visible:first').focus(); });
            }
        });
```

And It works!.

Well, but it doesn't the principal problem. The problem is when the modal is open, don't work my code jQuery.

This is my modal external:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
    <h3>Titulo modal</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="window">
        <div class="nom_epi"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:print();">Imprimir</a>
    <a class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</a>
</div>
```

If I put the code in the file original:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nom_epi').click(function() { alert("hello"); });
});
```

It doesn't work!
The external modal ignores Jquery code of the original file. It's strange because the bootstrap CSS interpreted good.

I think it is due to the jQuery code I use to open the external modal.

Comment: try changing code to $('body').on('click', '.nom_epi', function() { alert("hello"); })

Comment: you're welcome! check this out if you want to learn how it all works https://tutsplus.com/lesson/bind-live-delegate-huh/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're binding the event on document ready, so it only binds to elements that exist at that time. I suggest using the `on()` function instead.

The suggestion David gives in his comment should work fine:

> $('body').on('click', '.nom_epi', function() { alert("hello"); })

Generally you would try and bind the function to something further down the DOM tree, but these modals are usually direct children of `<body>`

Comment: You are a hero without a cape! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider if you click anywhere apart from your required DOM object and it still triggers the function execution; it will be kind of a mess. Hence, binding `click` event to `body` is not a recommended way as it will be heavy event binding. Try to to use `window.onLoad` function instead of `document.ready` within which you will keep binding function execution with same DOM object.

```
$(window).load(() => {

  $('.nom_epi').click((e) => { 
      console.debug("it is working"); 
  });

});
```